# How can I make a command sent through ssh die if the ssh connection is killed?

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line-interface

When using SSH to send a command to a remote server, if the SSH connection dies the process keeps running. Are there any ways to have it kill the child processes if the SSH connection ends?

Example:

```
root@local:~# ssh root@server sleep 100 &
[2] 15762

root@local:~# kill 15762
[2]+  Stopped                 ssh root@server sleep 100
```

After running the above, the sleep command is still running on the remote host.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it's any consolation, pretty much any task that writes to stdout will die due to a SIGPIPE (unless stdout is redirected on the remote host).

Answer (score 1):

Don't run it in the background in the first place. Thus, when the ssh conn dies, the process will be killed as well.

Answer (score 0):

jdizzle's comment gave me an idea: run your commands inside a script and handle signals with "trap" (http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/linuxcommand.org/wss0160.php)

would that do?

cheers,
eddy

Answer (score 0):

Log back in through SSH , run a ps -ef | grep `commandname` and kill the process?